# How work with foreign key in Entity Framework Core & ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, crud

Update Qustion: Part of my problem solve and thank to every one my create problem solve. for the show, now i write this code but i do not know how to show this to the view:

```
public IEnumerable<object> Paging(int page)
    {
        int t = (page - 1) * 10;
        DB db = new DB();

        //var q = db.Books.Skip(t).Take(10).ToList();

        var q = (from i in db.Books
                 select new
                 {
                     i.id,
                     i.BookName,
                     i.Writer,
                     i.BookcategFK.BookCategori,
                     i.inventory,
                     i.BannerImage,
                     
                 }
                 ).Skip(t).Take(10).ToList();

        return q;
    }
```

---

I create two tables `book` and `type`, and define a foreign key between them, but when I try to write data in the foreign key column, I get an error. This problem exists when I try to read them too.

Please help.

This is my controller code:

```
UploadFile UP = new UploadFile(Environment);

Book B = new Book();

BLBook BLB = new BLBook();

B.BookName = MBM.BookName;
B.BookcategFK.id = MBM.BookcategFK; // i get error in this line
B.CoverType = MBM.CoverType;
B.PublishedNumber = MBM.PublishedNumber;
B.BannerImage = UP.uploadBook(MBM.BannerImage);
        
B.Atleast = MBM.Atleast;
B.inventory = MBM.inventory;
B.Price = MBM.Price;
B.Discount = MBM.Discount;

BLB.Create(B,MBM.BookcategFK); 
        
return View("BookCreate");
```

This is my view markup:

```
  <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dropdownrole">دسته بندی :</label>
                <div class="custom-control custom-radio xmt-3">
                    <select class="custom-select mt-3" id="BookcategFK" name="BookcategFK">
                        @{
                            if (!Model.Any())
                            {

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                    <option value="@item.id">@item.BookCategori</option> // i get error here too
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="valid-feedback">acepte</div>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">fill it please</div>
            </div>
```

This is my model code:

```
namespace Online_Book_Shop.Models
{
public class BookModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public bool DS { get; set; }

    public string BookName { get; set; }

    public int BookcategFK { get; set; }

    
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
}
```

This is my business entity class:

```
public class Book
{
    public int id { get; set; }

    public bool DS { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }

    public BookCategorization BookcategFK { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For foreign key, need to mark with [ForeignKey] attribute.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
public class Book 
{ 
    public int id { get; set; } 
    public bool DS { get; set; } 
    public string BookName { get; set; } 
    [ForeignKey("BookcategFK")] // this name should match the field name in other class
    public BookModel BookcategFK { get; set; } 
    public string Publisher { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: the name in the annotation should match the class if it's applied over the id. but if it's applied over the object it should match the FK name  - see [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

BookcategFK if it is a foreign key which refers the value of primary key in another table, so check if the value of BookcategFK is exists in the other table.

EDIT
your implantation isn't clear to me, try it this way

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public List<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        return new List<Category>()
    {
        new Category() { Id = 1, Name = "History" },
        new Category() { Id = 2, Name = "Art" }
    };
    }
}


public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool DS { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }  



    public List<Book> GetBooks()
    {
        return new List<Book>()
        {
            new Book() {
                Id = 1,
                BookName = "ABC",
                DS = true,
                CategoryId = 1,
                Publisher = "The Pulisher",
            },

            new Book() {
                Id = 2,
                BookName = "XYZ",
                DS = true,
                CategoryId = 1,
                Publisher = "The Pulisher",
            },

        };
    }
}
```

Comment: it is exist. and my problem is for when i try fill my object before send to the server as i write above my error is in  B.BookcategFK.id = MBM.BookcategFK; line and the error message is object refrence not set to as instanst of an object

Comment: can you share your models?